# Why is cloning of file buffers prohibited?

Tags: buffers, files

Why does `clone-buffer` not work on file buffers.

I can make it work by the following advice:

```el
(advice-add 'clone-buffer :around
  (lambda (oldfun &rest args)
     "Allow cloning file buffers."
     (interactive "bName of new cloned buffer: ")
     (let (buffer-file-name)
       (apply oldfun args))))
```

The clone is a non-file buffer. One can modify it and save it into a new file with `save-buffer`.

Everything is working quite fine. So why does the original command `clone-buffer` test whether the current buffer is a file buffer and disallow cloning in that case?

---

My current best guess for the motivation of the restriction:
The change from a file buffer to a non-file buffer is quite hard.

Examples:

- Version control like `vc-git` does not work anymore.
- `compile-command` compiles the original buffer file and not the clone

Comment: Maybe to provide a layer of protection against users over-writing the original file with the modified clone? It wouldn't be difficult (for me at least) to get confused and choose the same file name as the original to save the clone to. The alternative workflow, starting with writing the original to a new file name, is arguably safer in this respect, since you establish the correct file-buffer association before making any changes to either file.

Comment: You might get an answer for such a design question here. But I'd probably ask it at emacs-devel@gnu.org if I were you. An answer here will likely either be just a guess, unless someone finds an explicit reference to this somewhere.

Comment: Interesting question! It looks like you can use `clone-buffer` on a file-visiting buffer created with `clone-indirect-buffer`. Does cloning from an indirect buffer fix the issues with `vc-git` and `compile-command`?

Comment: @Tyler In my use-case I clone the buffer and heavily modify the text for analysis purposes. I don't intent to write the clone back to a file.If I know that I want to save the clone to a file I would rather use `write-buffer` and `find-file` the old one when I need it again. Alternatively one could `insert` the `buffer-string` into a new file buffer if it is clear that one wants to keep the original buffer.

Comment: @Melioratus Nice observation. It indicates that `clone-indirect-buffer` is also faulty. It keeps `vc` mode despite it is not working there (`buffer-file-name` is nil). So it seems `vc` is not really the reason for restricting `clone-buffer` to non-file buffers.

Comment: `diff-buffer-with-file` was fixed not so long ago to handle being called from indirect buffers.  It may be sensible for other `vc` features to do likewise.  Raise bug reports, if there aren't any already.